# how to integrate odoo with IMDb?

Tags: python, api, web-services, integration, odoo

i'am trying to integare odoo with [imdb.com](https://imdb.com) which have it's own APIs on [omdbapi.com](https://www.omdbapi.com/) 
i need to fictch movies as products on odoo then make apurchase orders on it 
the site says for searching i should use this api http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey="i must but my key here"&t="the movie Name i want to search"

i'am tried to do it by this way

```
class Api(http.Controller):
@http.route('/api', auth='public', methods=["get"])
def index(self, **kw):
    url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=15439843&t=hello'
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text
```

it return a json with data of the movie hello 
but here it's a static parameter how can i make it dynamic and get the movie name from field or data input then i need to get the json parameters on method create of product.tempalte

```
add_product = http.request.env['product.template'].sudo().create({
         'name': "movie name form json"
         })
return add_product
```

any help well be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I used Postman to generate this code, this will give you an idea of how to handle query string param from the link

```
import requests
url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/"

querystring = {"apikey":"15439843","t":"hello"} # your parameters here in query string

headers = { 'Cache-Control': "no-cache", 'Connection': "keep-alive", 'cache-control': "no-cache" }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```